# Mandatory & Non-Mandatory

Tags: forms, required-fields, mandatory-fields

I have two radio options, and one password field.
Yes is checked, password below is mandatory and can be entered.
No is checked , password field is disabled and can not be edited.

Question is, should that password field label contain "*" mandatory mark?

Comment: There is a system that we use at my employer; normally, a certain field is not required, but when we make a change to a different field on the form, the certain field becomes required. At that time, the red asterisk is displayed, and additionally, a message is placed at the top of the form indicating that the field is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional forms and disabling input fields?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28191/conditional-forms-and-disabling-input-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You should activate (or make visible) the mandatory password field only if the "yes" radiobutton in selected.

Otherwise you can make a step by step process in which, if the "yes" option is selected, the following page asks for a password creation.